# Node JS Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/mysql_bindings'

Tags: node.js

I have installed Node.Js and Casper.js to perform webscraping and save the info into a DB. But I have a problem because when I try to execute the source, I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/mysql_bindings'
```

I have previously installed mysql-libmysqlclient with the mysql_bindings inside. I tested creating the route of the error, but it didn't work.

The code is:

```
var mysql = require('db-mysql'); 

new mysql.Database({ 
  hostname: 'localhost', 
  user: 'rool', 
  password: 'xxxx', 
  database: 'xxxBD' }).connect(function(error) { 
  if (error) { 
    return console.log('CONNECTION error: ' + error); 
  } 

  this.query(). 
    select('*'). 
    from('tablaPruebas'). 
    execute(function(error, rows, cols) { 
      if (error) { 
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error); 
        return; 
      } 
      console.log(rows.length + ' ROWS found'); 
  }); 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version are you using? There was an old bug that resulted in this error message but it was fixed 2 years ago. Also what modules do you have installed?

Comment: Hi! The version of nodejs is node-v0.10.24, the version of casperjs is n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9 and phantonjs version´s is phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-i686. But I remember that I download the last versions of each one.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you got an example js program that when run in node.js causes the error? This is so I can try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: var mysql = require('db-mysql');
new mysql.Database({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    user: 'rool',
    password: 'xxxx',
    database: 'xxxBD'
}).connect(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('CONNECTION error: ' + error);
    }
    this.query().
        select('*').
        from('tablaPruebas').
       
        execute(function(error, rows, cols) {
                if (error) {
                        console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
                        return;
                }
                console.log(rows.length + ' ROWS found');
        });
});

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your using the following in your code:

```
var mysql = require('db-mysql');
```

However your question shows that you have installed mysql-libmysqlclient. This means you should be using the following instead:

```
var mysql = require('mysql-libmysqlclient');
```

I presume you installed from https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient

The code you're using looks more like db-mysql which can be found [here](http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql/)

If you install via `npm install db-mysql` then you should be good. Have a look at the link I included for db-mysql as there appears to be a few dependencies (e.g. setting up `MYSQL_CONFIG` environment variable).

Comment: I get the same error with both options :-(. I have tried it whith:  npm install mysql.
 But I get the next error when I execute the code to connect to the DataBase: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __dirname                                  
  /opt/development/n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/index.js:2
  /opt/development/n1k0-casperjs-4f105a9/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/index.js:5